# Cant create a file with prefix "con.de." in the filename

Tags: windows, filesystems

what could be the reason for the error message,  when I want to create a file with the name "con.de.csv"?
I tried also "con.de.xls", with the same error.

Error: [image]

As you can see - it's Windows 10

Comment: From Google Translate:  The specified device name is not allowed.  Also, what duenni said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a blast from the past. `con` had a special meaning under MS-DOS, you simply can not name a file like that. There are other [reserved words](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/74496) you can't use.